# login validation loop executing else condition 'login failed' after 'login success'

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, loops, cordova

hi this form is meant to check database for username and password and to validate login.
This login page works fine but am stuck in a minor error. In the function ListDBValues() at login.js, Loop checks for database to match username and password. On sucessfull match it gives alert "Login success" but followed by "login failed", i have given break but know use. Where i am wrong? why does it executing else condition when the 1st criteria is matched?

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="css/theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
</head>

<body onLoad="onBodyLoad()">

    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="b">
        <div class="header" id="header" data-role="header">

            <h3>Registration</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="username" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="username"> Username </label>
                <input name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" value="" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="password" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" value="" type="password">
            </div>
            <input id="login" value="login" type="button" onClick="validationcheck()">
            <input id="register" value="register" type="button" onClick="register()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Login.js**

```
var db;
var shortName = 'WebSqlDB';
var version = '1.0';
var displayName = 'WebSqlDB';
var maxSize = 65535;

function successCallBack() {
    alert("DEBUGGING: success");

}

function onBodyLoad(){
    alert("DEBUGGING: we are in the onBodyLoad() function");
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
        return;
    }
    db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contacts(UserId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, fname TEXT NOT NULL, lname TEXT NOT NULL,age INTEGER NOT NULL,username TEXT NOT NULL,password TEXT NOT NULL)',[],nullHandler,errorHandler);
    },errorHandler,successCallBack);
}

/*The problem is in this function*/ 
function ListDBValues() {
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
        return;
    }    
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Contacts;', [],
            function(transaction, result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = result.rows.item(i);
                    var username1 = $('#username').val();

                    var password1 =  $('#password').val();

                    var uname=row.username;
                    var pasw=row.password;
                    if(username1==uname && password1==pasw){
                        alert("Login Success"); 
                        login();
                        break;


                    }

                    else

                    {
                        var status=1;
                    }
                }
                if(status==1)
                {
                    alert("login failed");
                }
            },errorHandler);
    },errorHandler,nullHandler);

    return;
}

function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
    alert('Error: ' + error.message + ' code: ' + error.code);

}

function nullHandler(){};

function login(){
    window.location="file:///android_asset/www/front.html";
};
function validationcheck(){
    if($("#username").val() == ""){
        alert("please enter username");
        $("#username").focus();
    }
    else if ($("#password").val() == "" ) {
        alert("Please enter password");
        $("#password").focus();
    }
    else
    {
        success();
    }
}
function success(){
    ListDBValues();
}

function register(){
    window.location="file:///android_asset/www/register.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's imagine that first row from table doesn't match required user and password. Than in "if-else" "else" is executed and status becomes equal to 1. So whether correct row will be found or not, status is already 1, and alert will be shown. The shortest fix will be to add

```
status = 0;
```

in "if" clause. For example:

```
login();
status = 0;
break;
```

Not directly connected with question advice: it's not good to fetch all table to check for user-password. Also it's not good to access same $("#id") in loop. I modified your function to show what i mean:

```
function ListDBValues() {
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
        return;
    }    
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        var username1 = $('#username').val();
        var password1 = $('#password').val();
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username1, password1], function(transaction, result) {
            if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                alert("Login Success"); 
                login();
            } else {
                alert("login failed");
            }
        }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler, nullHandler);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks a ton. It worked and thanks much for the idea, appreciate lot. i understood everything but whats this function(transaction, result) does?

Comment: @user2861229 we select rows, which have appropriate username and password. If there is at least one such row (actually, usually there is only one row, because of unique pair user-password, but maybe you have more than one row with same user-password for some reason), than login is successful. If there are no rows with these username and password, than login is failed